# Rails "has_many" association with NULL foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

Our Rails 3 application has models `Person` and `Message`.  Messages can be specific to a Person (when the message `person_id` column is set) or they can be "global" (when the `person_id` column is NULL).

We would like to have a simple `has_many` relationship using the [`:conditions` option](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to-label-Options) as such:

```ruby
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages,
      :conditions => proc { ['(messages.person_id IS NULL) OR ' +
                             '(messages.person_id = ?)'], self.id }
  # ...
end
```

But it appears that the `has_many` class method encodes the "conditions" option as a logical "AND" clause after enforcing the foreign key constraint of equality to the Person object's id (e.g. "`FROM messages WHERE person_id=123 AND (person_id IS NULL OR person_id=123)`").  It appears that there is no way to allow associated objects with null foreign keys to belong to such associations.

Does Rails 3 / ActiveRecord provide a way to do this or must I hack my own association-like methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an OR clause like you want using conditions on the ActiveRecord assocation.  You could have the association without conditions and then add a method to include the global messages you want.  That way you could still take advantage of the association when building associated records.

```
# person.rb
has_many :messages

def all_messages
  Message.where('messages.person_id=? OR messages.person_id IS NULL', id)
end
```

---

Here's my standard plug for the [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem, which is handy for more advanced queries like this if you don't want to have bits of SQL in your code.  Check it out.

Comment: unfortunately, this means you can't do things like: Person.limit(2).includes(:all_messages), since all_messages isn't an association.

Comment: @JoeVanDyk Yes, you're right.  However, doing includes(:all_messages) would execute an extra SQL query to do the eager-loading.  So beyond syntax there is no real difference in terms of performance from my suggestion.

Comment: Doing the includes(:all_messages) results in a maximum of one extra query. If you did Person.limit(100).includes(:all_messages), this results in two queries. If you used #all_messages above, that would be 101 queries to load everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're correct,  you could forgo has_many, and create a scope with an outer join, something like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :messages lambda { 
      joins("RIGHT OUTER Join messages on persons.id = messages.person_id")
      .where('persons.id = ?',self.id)
   }
```